# How to put a photo in a money bill?

Tags: image-processing

Me and some friends want to make a present for another friend and we want to put pictures of each of us, e.g., me

[image]

into a, e.g., one hundert dollar bill (replacing Benjamin Franklin and adequate color correction)

[image]

and as a watermark on the white left part of the 20 Euro Bill

[image]

I know I could use online stuff, e.g., https://photofunia.com/effects/100_dollars, but I would like to learn how to do this the geeky and fun way with Mathematica. Besides, I would like to print the generating code also for the present. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use [image histogram matching](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/comprehensive-image-processing-environment/match-image-histograms.html) to match the colours of the 100 dollar bill.

Comment: Hmmm... I dont know if I am using it correctly, it does not seem to match the colors very well, or the color space of the bill is just to poor, see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KOXlEVE8yQWEtYUE/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: Ah, my bad. It works better if you transform the face to monochrome, `ImageApply[{1, 1, 1} ({0.3, 0.6, 0.1}.#) &, face]`, and use only the face part of the bill, `ImageTrim[bill, First@FindFaces[bill]]`. Then you get https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gBWp.png

Comment: I think this is illegal.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a suggestion for getting the picture of your face to have the proper colors of the bill:

```
bill = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/niI83.jpg"];
face = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ub07.jpg"];

billColors = Sort[DominantColors[bill]]

quantize = ColorQuantize[face, 3];

faceColors = 
 Sort[RGBColor @@ # & /@ 
   DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[ImageData[quantize], 1]]]

ColorReplace[ColorQuantize[face, 3], Thread[faceColors -> billColors]]
```

[image]

While this doesn't address the whole problem, it's one step of it. You might also find the [FindFaces](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFaces.html) function useful as well:

```
boxes = FindFaces[bill];
HighlightImage[bill, Rectangle @@@ boxes]
```

[image]

but it would take a little more effort to get this to work well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Is the first code block correct? I get an error for `ColorReplace`. Also, in the second code block, should it be `bill` instead of `i` in `HighlightImage`?

Comment: The first code block works well for me, see https://puu.sh/vw8EK/526dbd8804.png. And yes, you were correct about my second code bloc, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks, weird, in my Mathematica version 11.0.1, I get 4 dominant colors for the bill, see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KSFRWbUg3U0U1UXM/view?usp=sharing . You got 3, that was my problem in the arguments of `ColorReplace`

Comment: Is there any difference between your `faceColors` and `Sort@DominantColors@quantize`?

Comment: @MauricioLobos interesting. You can do something like `quantize = ColorQuantize[face, Length@billColors]` which would work pretty well. Regarding your second question, for some reason the colors look slightly different. Would take some more investigation as to why that is, but for some reason they don't look the same when I examine the underlying numbers that generate the colors. I like the idea though.